# Getting Picasso to pre-fetch forthcoming images

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I'm using Picasso with a GridView, loading 200 images over the network. Right now it looks like Picasso is not triggering an image load over the network until the image starts to come into view on the screen.

Is there a way to have Picasso pre-fetch the next N images in the list so that the experience is better? I am using an Adapter to put the images into the Gridview.

Comment: I think you have to try AndroidQuery instead of picasso.

Comment: @DaBeeeenster have you implemented the correct answer of Bill Mote. please share

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I am prefetching images into a cache very successfully using Picasso like so:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
     Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
     Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).setLoggingEnabled(true);
}
for (Article article : articleList) {
     ArrayList<String> images = article.getImages();
     for (String url : images) {
          if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
               Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .resizeDimen(R.dimen.article_image_preview_width, R.dimen.article_image_preview_height)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .fetch();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing. can You explain here what is Article? can you share the more code

Comment: Assume Article is just some POJO that contains an ArrayList of Strings that are image URLs.

Comment: OK. this code will just only cache the images in memory/DIsk. so how to display cached images in my listview/Gridview?

Comment: Instead of .fetch() you'd use .into() with your ImageView.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi you were playing saw with the client?

Comment: @AhmedHegazy It was russian roulette