# Does Picasso apply resize options during fetch()?

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I am referring to this post [Getting Picasso to pre-fetch forthcoming images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883034/getting-picasso-to-pre-fetch-forthcoming-images) where @BillMote uses fetch() with centerCrop() and further options:

```
           Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(url)
                .resizeDimen(R.dimen.article_image_preview_width, R.dimen.article_image_preview_height)
                .centerCrop()
                .fetch();
```

Will Picasso honor such options at all, or will Picasso save the image straight to the cache so these options are ignored and should be used later when the image is pulled from the cache and viewed?

It still isn't clear to me (and after 6 months I haven't found any documentation where this was clearly defined [I admit I haven't investigated into this either]) if Picasso applies any such options before saving the file to the cache, or repeatedly every time it displays an image.

Something like centerCrop() makes no sense to me in above statement, because the size of the target ImageView isn't clear at this point. This might be different for resizeDimen(), but I stil doubt Picasso will apply the dimensions because [JakeWharton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/132047/jake-wharton) once said in a post that Picasso relies on okhttp for image caching.

Can anybody shed light please.

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: It should. If it doesn't its a bug.

Comment: I hope this is gonna be helpful to you  http://square.github.io/picasso/