# How to make use of cached data in my app?

Tags: android, caching

How to cache list data(images and names) in retrofit? Any suitable example for caching data will be more helpful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caching Images and strings using Retrofit, okhttp, picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098999/caching-images-and-strings-using-retrofit-okhttp-picasso)

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I have no idea about it.I m new in android development. so looking for any suitable example for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. first of all you have to check headers coming in your api through postman. There you will see "Cache-Control" header. In this header, there has to be public cache value if you want to cache that api. Here is the code :

In your ApiClient.class where u kept your base URL, make this method :

```
public static CacheControl getCacheControl(CachePolicy cachePolicy) {
   switch (cachePolicy) {
       case CACHE_ONLY:
           return CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE;
       case NETWORK_ONLY:
           return CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK;

       case NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE:
           return new CacheControl.Builder().maxAge(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).maxStale(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

       case FRESH_CASHE_ELSE_NETWORK:
           return new CacheControl.Builder().maxAge(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).minFresh(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();


       case CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK:
          return new CacheControl.Builder().immutable().build();

   }
   return null;
```

}

Now make an enum class to keep these constants :

```
 public enum CachePolicy {
 CACHE_ONLY,
 NETWORK_ONLY,
 NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE,
 FRESH_CASHE_ELSE_NETWORK,
 CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
 }
```

Paste this method in your ApiClient class with your base url :

```
public static Retrofit getClientAuthenticationWithCache(Context context, CacheControl
       cacheControl) {
   String URL_BASE = "your base url";
   long cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;  //10MiB
   Cache cache = new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);



   Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
       @Override
       public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
           Request request = chain.request();
           request = request.newBuilder().cacheControl(cacheControl).build();
           return chain.proceed(request);
       }
   };

   OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
           .cache(cache)
           .addInterceptor(interceptor)
           .build();

   Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl(URL_BASE)
           .client(okHttpClient)
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

   return builder.build();
```

}

Now use this method in the activity/fragment where you are getting response as follow :

```
ApiClient.getClient(applicationContext, ApiClient.getCacheControl(CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE)).create(ApiInterface::class.java)
```